# How to show the Math.sin() result when I input a degree?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to create a HTML that I can type a degree,and click the button, the result of its sin shows, and I know that the Math.sin function will see the input value as radian ,so I add a line that multiply the input value *Math.PI/180,but it suddenly doesn't work, which shows "NaN". I will post these two version of my work. Please somebody help me to find what the problem is.[This is the version of radian](https://i.stack.imgur.com/buNwv.png) 
[This is the version of degree, which is the way that I want to try,and the coding is down below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYZEo.png)

```js
function convert() {

    var deg = document.getElementById("an");
    var ang = deg * Math.PI / 180;
    var si = Math.sin(ang.value);
    console.log(si);
    sc.innerHTML += si
}
```

```html
 <input type="text" id="an" />
    <input type="button" id="sub" value="click" onclick="convert()" />
    <div id="sc">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
var deg = document.getElementById("an");
```

and

```
   var si = Math.sin(ang.value);
```

To

```
var deg = document.getElementById("an").value;
```

and

```
   var si = Math.sin(ang);
```

```js
function convert(){

       var deg = document.getElementById("an").value;
       var ang = deg* Math.PI/180;
       var si = Math.sin(ang);
       sc.innerHTML += si}
```

```html
    <body>
      <input type="text" id="an"/>
      <input type="button" id="sub" value="click" onclick="convert()"/>
      <div id="sc">
      </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) function to parse the value to numeric before calculating:

```js
function convert(){
   var deg = parseInt(document.querySelector("#an").value) || 0;
   var ang = deg* Math.PI/180;
   var si = Math.sin(ang);
   document.querySelector("#sc").innerText = si;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="an"/>
<input type="button" id="sub" value="click" onclick="convert()"/>
<div id="sc"></div>
```

Also, you may want to use [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) instead of `getElementById`.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `input`, not value inside `input`

And `ang.value` is wrong Syntex because `ang` is not input element:

```html
<script>
   function convert(){

   var deg = document.getElementById("an").value;
   var ang = deg * (Math.PI/180);
   var si = Math.sin(ang);
   sc.innerHTML += si;}
</script>
<body>
  <input type="text" id="an"/>
  <input type="button" id="sub" value="click" onclick="convert()"/>
  <div id="sc">
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
< script > function convert ()
{
  var deg = document.getElementById ("an").value;
  // var sc = document.getElementById("sc");
  var ang = parseInt (deg) * Math.PI / 180;
  var si = Math.sin (ang);
sc.innerHTML += si}

</script >
  <body >
  <input type = "text" id = "an" / ><input type = "button" id = "sub" value =
  "click" onclick = "convert()" / ><div id = "sc" > </div > </body >
```

Answer (score 1):

You should extract value from ## Input ## using the value attribute. And pass it as a Number.

input

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
   <input type="text" id="an"/>
      <input type="button" id="sub" value="click" onclick="convert()"/>
      <div id="sc">
      </div>

<script>
   function convert(){
       var deg = document.getElementById("an").value || 0;
       var ang = Number(deg) * Math.PI/180;
       var si = Math.sin(ang);
       sc.innerHTML += si}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

## Quick solution to your code

In this line.

```
var si = Math.sin(ang.value);
```

you are using `ang.value`, which is undefine, and `Math.sin(ang.value)` i.e `Math.sin(undefined)` giving you NaN.

Try removing `.value` and it will work.

```
var si = Math.sin(ang);
```

## Complete Code

```html
<script>

       function convert(){
       var deg = document.getElementById("an").value;
       var ang = deg* Math.PI/180;
       var si = Math.sin(ang);
       sc.innerHTML += si
     }

    </script>
    <body>
      <input type="text" id="an"/>
      <input type="button" id="sub" value="click" onclick="convert()"/>
      <div id="sc">
      </div>
    </body>
```